# EF Core ignores some of my mapping configuration

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a class for my model and another class for mapping models with EF Core. When I add a migration, EF Core ignores my mapping configuration.

For example, the max length for all properties is max.

Here's my code:

Model class:

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public double UnitPrice { get; private set; }
    public bool IsInStock { get; private set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Picture { get; private set; }
    public string PictureAlt { get; private set; }
    public string PictureTitle { get; private set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; private set; }
    public string Slug { get; private set; }
    public string Keywords { get; private set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; private set; }
    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping class:

```
public class ProductMapping:IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Products");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Code).HasMaxLength(15).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.ShortDescription).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Picture).HasMaxLength(1000);
        builder.Property(x => x.PictureAlt).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(x => x.PictureTitle).HasMaxLength(500);
        builder.Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);

        builder.Property(x => x.Keywords).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.MetaDescription).HasMaxLength(150).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Slug).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.Category)
            .WithMany(x => x.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

Migration :

```
public partial class ProductAdd : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Products",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Code = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                UnitPrice = table.Column<double>(type: "float", nullable: false),
                IsInStock = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                ShortDescription = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Picture = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PictureAlt = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                PictureTitle = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                CategoryId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                Slug = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Keywords = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                MetaDescription = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                CreationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Products", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Products_ProductCategories_CategoryId",
                    column: x => x.CategoryId,
                    principalTable: "ProductCategories",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Products_CategoryId",
            table: "Products",
            column: "CategoryId");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Products");
    }
}
```

My context:

```
public class ShopContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ShopContext(DbContextOptions<ShopContext> options):base(options)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ProductCategory).Assembly;
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually add `ProductMapping` to the configuration? I.e. is it in the same assembly?

Comment: Looks like by some unknown reason the configuration code is not called. In order to verify that, try calling it explicitly - `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductAdd());`. Why btw it is `partial`, is there something not shown here?

Comment: yes  my product and ProductCategory and my context are in the same  class library

Comment: with your suggest i try with "modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductAdd());" and it is working

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the classes, so disregard the last part about `partial` class. I meant, try `modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductMapping());`. If that works, then `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(assembly);` is not finding `ProductMapping` class, make sure it is in the same assembly as `ProductCategory` class.